# Convert character to 12-hour format R

Tags: r, datetime

I was trying to convert the Departure / Arrival time (character) to a 12-hour format (%I:%M %p). But it only gives me this..

```
FlightData$DepartureAEST <- strptime(FlightData$DepartureAEST, "%I:%M %p")
```

What does POSIXlt mean? and how can i show the time properly (9:30 AM or 10:30 PM)?

[image: see image]

Answer (score 0):

2 answers for 2 questions:

#### 1 What does POSIXlt mean:

`POSIXlt` is a object class for date-time value in `R`, basically it's like a named list, with several elements representing time-related information. Like this:

```
x <- strptime("13:34:45", format = "%H:%M:%S")
class(x)
str(x)
unlist(x)
```

[image]

Fore each element's meaning, you should find more details in `Rdocument`:

```
?DateTimeClasses
```

[image]

#### 2 How can you show the time properly (9:30 AM or 10:30 PM)?

In this case, if you already have class `POSIXlt` as input, you can simply try the `format` function to convert input back into string vector. As:

```
y <- format(x, format = "%I:%M %p")
print(y)
class(y)
```

Hope these answers can help.

[image]